# When does Wireshark timestamp captured packets?

Tags: wireshark, timestamp

when does Wireshark timestamp the packets? After fully receiving a frame? Or already at receiving the first bytes of a frame? I read the following description about [Wireshark timestamps](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTimestamps.html) but this text only states: "While packets are captured, each packet is time stamped as it comes in".

Consider the following scenario and an accurate OS time:

sender ---->   Wireshark ---->   receiver

The sender starts the transmission of the frame at time x. The frame is fully received at the receiver at time y (y = transmission start x + frame length / link speed). Will the captured frame appear in the Wireshark with a timestamp close to x or will it be y?

Best regards, 
Jonas

Answer (score 5):

Well, Wireshark doesn't time stamp the packets itself; it relies on libpcap to do them and, on almost all operating systems, libpcap doesn't time stamp them itself, either, the OS's packet capture mechanism, as used by libpcap does.  The main exception is Windows, where WinPcap has to provide its own capture mechanism in the kernel, atop NDIS, but the mechanism behaves very similarly to the mechanisms inside most UN*Xes, and will give similar behavior.  (The other exception is HP-UX, where the OS's capture mechanism doesn't time-stamp packets at all, so libpcap does so; that gives answers that are somewhat similar to other OSes, but with a potentially even longer delay before the packets are time-stamped.)

If Wireshark (or any *other* packet sniffer!) is run on the sender, the packets will be "wrapped around" within the OS and handed to the capture mechanism; the time stamp could be applied before the sender starts transmitting the packet, but the time stamp will be closer to x than to y.

If Wireshark (or any other packet sniffer) is run on the receiver, the time stamp is applied at some time after the entire packet has been received; that could involve delays due to packet being queued up, interrupts being "batched", some amount of network-stack processing being done before the packet is time stamped, etc..  The time stamp will be closer to y than to x.

If Wireshark (or any other packet sniffer) is being run on some third machine, passively sniffing a network, the time stamp will probably be closer to y than to x, but there's a difference due to the receiver and the sniffer being separate machines that might see the packet at different times, have different code paths for receiving, etc..

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! In my situation Wireshark is running at a PC that is connected to a switch port which mirrors all traffic from the specified switch port. For my analysis, the sender is the switch which forwards the frames.

Comment: OK, this is "third-party" sniffing.  If the "receiver" is the machine running Wireshark (rather than the machine to which the packet is being sent), then the time stamp will be closer to y than x.